# Shortcut for tabn & tabp in vim/vi

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

When I open several files using `vim+tabf`, switching across the files will involve using `tabp` & `tabn`.

Can I have a quicker way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vim you can replace any command with a shortcut key sequence.
For tabp and tabp you might want to use ctrl-k and ctrl-j.
To create that mapping you would add the following to your .vimrc:

```
nmap <C-k> :tabn<cr>
nmap <C-j> :tabp<cr>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, vim maps `gt` to `:tabn` and `gT` to `:tabp` - this can be useful if you're logged into a server without your vimrc on it, or if you are logged in as root on a machine other people have to use.

But when I do have my vimrc, I use `<C-h>` and `<C-l>` for switching tabs.